# search recent in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a table named 'transactions', in which i store a user's all transactions. i want an mysql query such that it would extract recent 3 transactions from table for a specific user id.
i know i can use limit.

`SELECT * FROM 'transactions' WHERE 'userid'=20 LIMIT 0,3;`

but how can i access attributes of different transactions which are returned as object after query? also using limit 0,3 would start search from start of table but i want to start search from bottom of table. I am using it with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you are not using a programming language, and just `mysql`, all your attributes would be displayed in the query result in the console window.

**Edit**:

To access your query and results, see the following article on PHP.net's website: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

**/EndEdit**

To sort newest first, assuming you have a `id` column, use `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM 'transactions' WHERE 'userid'=20 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3;
```